# Calling javascript function else where in the page?

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript function that looks like this:

```
sendData: function(event) {

///my code////

},
```

I need to call this function somewhere in my page in an setInterval function.

So i tried this:

```
function myTimeoutFunction()
{   

    sendData();

}
myTimeoutFunction();
setInterval(myTimeoutFunction, 3000);
```

But this doesn't seem to fire up the function!

I also tried this way with no result:

```
function myTimeoutFunction()
{   

    this.sendData();

}
```

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @ochi, no. no errors in the console.

Comment: You'll need to show a more complete example. It's impossible to tell where that function is, other than that it seems to be inside an object.

Comment: we'll need more code then.  How about adding a [mcve] to the question?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/zunumojuye/1/edit?js,console — The function you provided is not syntactically valid JavaScript. It looks like you cut it out of the middle of something. Your attempt to use `this.sendData` is presumably trying to access that something, but there isn't enough context to tell what either *the something* or *this* actually refer to. You need to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax:

```
sendData: function(event) {
  ///my code////
},
```

Implies that your code is part of a larger, `Object` structure, similar to this:

```
var myObj = {
  sendData: function(event) {
    ///my code////
  },
  somethingElse: true
}
```

That being the case, how you call the function will depend on from where you are trying to call it:

If you are trying to call the function from inside of the object structure, you can access the function with the `this` keyword as long as the object has been instantiated:

```js
var myObj = {
  sendData: function(event) {
    console.log("Hello!");
  },
  runSendData: function(){
    // As long as you are inside of the same object structure
    // as the function you wish to invoke, you can use "this"
    this.sendData();
  }
}
    
myObj.runSendData();
```

If you are trying to call the function from outside of the object structure, you'll have to access your function as a method of the object it is defined within:

```js
var myObj = {
  sendData: function(event) {
    console.log("Hello!");
  },
  somethingElse: true
}
    
myObj.sendData();
```

If your goal is to just be able to call the function, independent of anything else, then you need to create it as  "function declaration", which happens outside of an object:

```js
function sendData(){
  console.log("Hello");
}

// Now you can invoke the function as long as it has been already read into memory
sendData();
```

Answer (score 2):

sendData seems to be a part of an object such as below

```
object = {
    sendData: function() {

    }
}
```

then you should call it like this.

```
object.sendData();
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score -2):

```
var sendData = function(params) {
    //Code
}
```

You can call your function with;

```
sendData(params);
```